# How to make multiple items purchase request to Google Play in-app billing feature

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am working on a project where we sell variety of virtual goods. I want to show these virtual goods and let him buy multiple items at once. But the Google's in-app billing takes only one item at a time, accoring to what I understand.

```
Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("REQUEST_PURCHASE");
request.putString(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_ITEM_ID, mProductId);
```

How do I call the in-app billing api and pass multiple item ids at once? Is that allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between managed and unmanaged in-app product android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391123/difference-between-managed-and-unmanaged-in-app-product-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible at the moment, only separate purchases per item, check out this answer for a workaround:

[Android in-app multiple purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660646/android-in-app-multiple-purchases)

Comment: [v4 of in-app billing library](https://youtu.be/tc57iyl06ww?t=578) will support this feature.