# Android In-app Billing, multiple purchases of the same item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Is there a way to buy a multiple of an ***item*** (SKU)?

For example: I have an SKU named **LifePoint**, and i want to buy **100 LifePoint**.

(in another word **N** * **my_item**).

I found this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660890/4224337), but am looking for something better.

PS: I'am using In-app Billing *Version 3*  and my item is *Unmanaged* (to buy my product many times).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you can do is after purchasing the item store it locally on the device and consume it immediately so that its again availiable to purchase. Ex:- Buy Energy add it to users profile and consume energy from item list like this user can buy as many energy he want. I am not sure this can be done for unmanaged items.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Shivaraj2 , but am using [Unmanaged][1] item, to enable buying my product many times. So i don't need to store it locally on the device and consume it immediately as you suggest. Also, what if the user want 100* this item? it will do the buy action 100 times?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9391332/4224337

Comment: ya agreed bro :) To buy 100 you have to create new Item with pkg of 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's been made deliberately impossible to do that to prevent apps from stealing large amounts of money from the user. Each purchase requires confirmation using the Google in-app billing popup which stops that kind of thing happening.

The way I've done something similar is to set up different SKU's (as in the answer you linked to) but to use the SKU 'title' field to decide how many items to award the player. If you do it that way you can easily change those values in the Google Play console without having to update your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i'll wait for other suggestions otherwise i'll accept your answer.

Comment: no problem, I know it's more speculation the answer